# SSL Test Server with typicals Flaws

Tags: tls, proxy

i am testing different SSL-Proxys and want to know more about their failure-handling.

Do you know about an public (test)server (HTTPS) which provides the typical flaws like:

- Expired certificate
- Self-signed certificate
- Multiple Domains (SNI)
- etc

Edit: An testsuite/tool would be fine too.

p.S. i am not looking for an SSL-testsite like SSLlabs

thank you in advance!

Comment: So you're looking for a place that you can use as a target? In general, recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes, a target, or a tool/testsuite for an dedicatet http-server.

Okay, i did not know that such questions are off-topic. Sorry about that!

Comment: You might want to check https://www.tls-o-matic.com/

Comment: Thank you very much!
https://www.tls-o-matic.com/
is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A good general tool to use when testing and learning about pen-testing is [Kali Linux](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kali.org%2F&ei=4a0rVdjgDbCPsQS0rIGwDA&usg=AFQjCNHczlD7OWcngq_h2VJY_s8Tx3BK8A&sig2=Lp0FYCtLZkHq1eR6joNd1A&bvm=bv.90491159,d.cWc). It comes with both test targets and tools. You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.virtualbox.org%2F&ei=Rq4rVb-_I-LHsQTt2YDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHpshI_45ZdaFl7Mvf-glSeroKujQ&sig2=FJrx3Hn5--ldPowRArhawg&bvm=bv.90491159,d.cWc) to host it on an existing machine if you don't have another machine to use.